# JPA Criteria API group_concat usage

Tags: jpa, group-concat

I am currently working on a report which needs a group_concat for one of the fields.

```
CriteriaQuery<GameDetailsDto> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder
                .createQuery(GameDetailsDto.class);
Root<BetDetails> betDetails = criteriaQuery.from(BetDetails.class);
Expression<String> betSelection = betDetails.get("winningOutcome");
criteriaQuery.multiselect(
    // other fields to select
    criteriaBuilder.function("group_concat", String.class, betSelection),
    // other fields to select
    );
//predicate, where clause and other filters

TypedQuery<GameDetailsDto> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

this throws a null pointer exception on the line:

```
TypedQuery<GameDetailsDto> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
```

did i incorrectly use the function method of the criteriaBuilder?

the documentations says:

```
function(String name, Class<T> type, Expression<?>... args);
```

Comment: Include the stack trace for the null pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with Hibernate-jpa-mysql:

1.) created a GroupConcatFunction class extending org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction (this is for single column group_concat for now)

```
public class GroupConcatFunction implements SQLFunction {

@Override
public boolean hasArguments() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Type getReturnType(Type firstArgumentType, Mapping mapping)
        throws QueryException {
    return StandardBasicTypes.STRING;
}

@Override
public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List arguments,
        SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
    if (arguments.size() != 1) {
        throw new QueryException(new IllegalArgumentException(
                "group_concat shoudl have one arg"));
    }
    return "group_concat(" + arguments.get(0) + ")";
}
```

}

2.) i created the CustomMySql5Dialect class extending org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect and registered the group_concat class created in step 1

3.) On the app context, i updated the jpaVendorAdapter to use the CustomMySql5Dialect as the databasePlatform

4.) Finally to use it

```
criteriaBuilder.function("group_concat", String.class,
        sampleRoot.get("sampleColumnName"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution: instead of creating the whole class, just use `SQLFunctionTemplate`.

```
new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "group_concat(?1)")
```

and then register this function in your own SQL dialect (eg. in constructor)

```
public class MyOwnSQLDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

  public MyOwnSQLDialect() {
    super();
    this.registerFunction("group_concat", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "group_concat(?1)"));
  }
}
```

Comment: how will this work. `MyOwnSQLDialect.class` is not a spring `@Component. so how will the program pick this class up. Can you add few more details.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor = com.inn.core.generic.utils.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
```

and class:

```
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderContributor;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor implements MetadataBuilderContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("config_json_extract",
                new StandardSQLFunction("json_extract", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("JSON_UNQUOTE",
                new StandardSQLFunction("JSON_UNQUOTE", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction("group_concat", 
                new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));

    }

}
```