# How to do group_concat under (Open)JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, openjpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there any possibility to do `group_concat()` under JPA?
I have the following statement:

```
# Pseudoquery
SELECT
    t0.id,
    MAX(t0.created),
    GROUP_CONCAT(t3.id),
    MIN(t2.created),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.createdby)
FROM
    t0
JOIN
    t1 ON t0.id = t1.id
JOIN
    t2 ON t2.id = t0.oid
JOIN
    t3 ON t3.oid = t2.oid
WHERE
    t1.created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW() AND
    t3.id LIKE 'L%'
GROUP BY
    t0.id
;
```

Is there any way to transform this to a JPA-Query?

I'm using Spring-Data-JPA together with OpenJPA. Is there a possible way (besides a native Query)?

Comment: The link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005354/jpa-criteria-api-group-concat-usage may help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've seen similar advices - but the downside is, that I am not using Criteria_API. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I'am facing the same problem.please share the solution if you got.

Comment: @Salman I dismissed doing it with OpenJPA.