# MySQL Group by query for specific condition

Tags: mysql, jpa, group-by, sql-order-by

If I want to know the total amount of salary on each customer, then GROUP BY query would be as follows:

```
SELECT NAME, SUM(SALARY) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;
```

But, if I don't want sum of salaries and just need to look all salaries grouped by name then what will be query or approach?

Comment: Maybe `GROUP_CONCAT()` instead of `SUM()`

Comment: Why 'grouped by' as opposed to 'arranged by'?

Comment: @Paul group_concat is what I was looking for but in JPA query group_concat not works. Any idea what I can do in JPA query for group_concat?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which salary you want to show..

Option 1 -> maximum:

```
SELECT NAME, max(SALARY) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;
```

Option 2 -> minimum:

```
SELECT NAME, min(SALARY) FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;
```

Option 3 -> list of them:

```
SELECT NAME, group_concat(SALARY separator ',') FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;
```

And last option -> doesn't matter :

```
SELECT NAME,SALARY FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: One more option: group on application site instead of SQL.

Comment: One more option on how to do it, I talked about all the options that he could want. @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Maybe OP just doesn't know what's possible in his application language. For example with PHP PDO you can use something like `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP)` and keep the result more flexible, because it's an array. On the other hand it's also simple to parse the resulting string - so everything is fine :-)

Comment: @sagi group_concat is what I was looking for but in JPA query group_concat not works. Any idea what I can do in JPA query for group_concat?

Comment: @ShobhitSingh You can find what you need here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005354/jpa-criteria-api-group-concat-usage

Comment: @sagi in this post criteriaquery is using but i am not using that. I just create jpa query using stringbuilder and use createQuery method of entity manager for getting query object. Does any built-in function exists is like group_concat and which also allowed in JPA query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [GROUP BY clause](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) for getting desired results.

```
SELECT NAME,SALARY FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve name and variation of salary for each customers (grouped by name and salary). You can try this.

```
SELECT name, salary FROM customers GROUP BY name, salary;
```