# JPA CrieteriaBuilder function for Oracle LISTAGG

Tags: function, jpa, criteria, listagg

Oracle function LISTAGG, for example,

```
SELECT department_id "Dept.",
       LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date) "Employees"
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY department_id
  ORDER BY department_id;
```

How to use CrieteriaBuilder function method for the LISTAGG funciton?

Thanks.

Comment: JPA CriteriaBuilder has "function" to invoke random SQL functions.

Comment: it must be in the format of  functionName(param1,param2).  But LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date) is not the format. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave, did you ever find an answer to your question here?

Comment: @AbhinavRai you've maybe moved on but I was able to get it to work following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7400104/1050369) example. Also, window functions like listagg have been added to Hibernate 6 if you're using that for your JPA implementation.